# Generating confidence interval for difference between 2 AUCs

Tags: r, roc, auc

I am trying to get a confidence interval for the difference between 2 AUCs for paired ROC curves. I've been reading the paper *pROC: an open-source package for R and S+ to analyze and compare ROC curves*, and they mention that there are ways to compare paired roc curves, but the methods mentioned in there seem to refer to something else. Is there a solid R package that can compute this or some text that describes how this is done?

Comment: Note that there's a feature request for pROC that suggests to do exactly that: https://github.com/xrobin/pROC/issues/73